# How do I make ggrepel move (some) labels outside US map boundaries?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel

I'm trying to create my first map using ggrepel, but as you can see I've instead created a dumpster fire of overlapping labels. Most of the locations I'm mapping and labelling are clustered in the northeast, so the labels overlap. How do I get some of the labels to slide over beyond the map boundaries (in the ocean, so to speak)? Here's the code I used to create this monster:

```
plot_usmap(fill = "light blue", alpha = 0.5) +
  ggrepel::geom_label_repel(data = top_18_2_transformed, aes(x=x, y=y, label=INSTNM),
                            size=3,
                            label.padding = unit(.75,"mm"),
                            nudge_y = 20,
                            nudge_x = 20,
                            box.padding=0.3,
                            max.overlaps=30,
                            point.padding=NA,
                            family="Avenir Next",
                            fill="gray99",
                            alpha=1.0,
                            label.r=unit(0.2,"lines"),
                            min.segment.length = 0.1,
                            label.size=unit(.15,"mm"),
                            segment.color="black",
                            segment.size=1,seed=1000) +
  geom_point(data = top_18_2_transformed, aes(x = x, y = y, size = UGDS),
             color = "red",
             alpha = 0.75) +
  labs(title = "Select Colleges",
       size = "Undergrad Enrollment") +
  theme(legend.position = "right")
```

And here's a picture of my problematic map:
[image]

Thanks in advance for any corrections you may be able to offer.

UPDATE 31 March 2022: here's the `dput(top_18_2_transformed)`:

```
structure(list(lon = c(-74.659365, -122.167359, -78.937624, -75.19391, 
-71.093226, -77.073463, -118.125878, -117.709837, -71.222839, 
-79.941993, -72.926688, -76.483084, -73.961885, -71.169242, -74.025334, 
-75.380236, -70.624084, -71.118313), lat = c(40.348732, 37.429434, 
36.001135, 39.950929, 42.359243, 38.908809, 34.137349, 34.106515, 
42.385995, 40.44357, 41.311158, 42.4472, 40.808286, 42.336213, 
40.744776, 40.606822, 41.739072, 42.374471), UNITID = c(186131, 
243744, 198419, 215062, 166683, 131496, 110404, 115409, 164739, 
211440, 130794, 190415, 190150, 164924, 186867, 213543, 166692, 
166027), OPEID = c(262700, 130500, 292000, 337800, 217800, 144500, 
113100, 117100, 212400, 324200, 142600, 271100, 270700, 212800, 
263900, 328900, 218100, 215500), OPEID6 = c(2627, 1305, 2920, 
3378, 2178, 1445, 1131, 1171, 2124, 3242, 1426, 2711, 2707, 2128, 
2639, 3289, 2181, 2155), INSTNM = c("Princeton University", "Stanford University", 
"Duke University", "University of Pennsylvania", "Massachusetts Institute of Technology", 
"Georgetown University", "California Institute of Technology", 
"Harvey Mudd College", "Bentley University", "Carnegie Mellon University", 
"Yale University", "Cornell University", "Columbia University in the City of New York", 
"Boston College", "Stevens Institute of Technology", "Lehigh University", 
"Massachusetts Maritime Academy", "Harvard University"), CITY = c("Princeton", 
"Stanford", "Durham", "Philadelphia", "Cambridge", "Washington", 
"Pasadena", "Claremont", "Waltham", "Pittsburgh", "New Haven", 
"Ithaca", "New York", "Chestnut Hill", "Hoboken", "Bethlehem", 
"Buzzards Bay", "Cambridge"), STABBR = c("NJ", "CA", "NC", "PA", 
"MA", "DC", "CA", "CA", "MA", "PA", "CT", "NY", "NY", "MA", "NJ", 
"PA", "MA", "MA"), ZIP = c("08544-0070", "94305", "27708", "19104-6303", 
"02139-4307", "20057-0001", "91125", "91711", "02452-4705", "15213-3890", 
"6520", "14853", "10027", "2467", "07030-5991", "18015", "02532-1803", 
"2138"), ACCREDAGENCY = c("Middle States Commission on Higher Education", 
"Western Association of Schools and Colleges Senior Colleges and University Commission", 
"Southern Association of Colleges and Schools Commission on Colleges", 
"Middle States Commission on Higher Education", "New England Commission on Higher Education", 
"Middle States Commission on Higher Education", "Western Association of Schools and Colleges Senior Colleges and University Commission", 
"Western Association of Schools and Colleges Senior Colleges and University Commission", 
"New England Commission on Higher Education", "Middle States Commission on Higher Education", 
"New England Commission on Higher Education", "Middle States Commission on Higher Education", 
"Middle States Commission on Higher Education", "New England Commission on Higher Education", 
"Middle States Commission on Higher Education", "Middle States Commission on Higher Education", 
"New England Commission on Higher Education", "New England Commission on Higher Education"
), INSTURL = c("www.princeton.edu/", "www.stanford.edu/", "www.duke.edu/", 
"www.upenn.edu/", "web.mit.edu/", "www.georgetown.edu/", "www.caltech.edu/", 
"https://www.hmc.edu/", "www.bentley.edu/", "www.cmu.edu/", "https://www.yale.edu/", 
"www.cornell.edu/", "www.columbia.edu/", "www.bc.edu/", "www.stevens.edu/", 
"www.lehigh.edu/", "https://www.maritime.edu/", "www.harvard.edu/"
), SCH_DEG = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3), PREDDEG = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3), HIGHDEG = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), REGION = c(2, 8, 5, 2, 1, 2, 8, 8, 1, 2, 1, 
2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1), CCBASIC = c(15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 
21, 18, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 22, 15), ADM_RATE = c(0.0578, 
0.0434, 0.076, 0.0766, 0.067, 0.1436, 0.0642, 0.1367, 0.4672, 
0.1544, 0.0608, 0.1085, 0.0545, 0.2722, 0.3996, 0.321, 0.9146, 
0.0464), ACTCM25 = c(33, 32, 33, 33, 34, 31, 35, 33, 27, 33, 
33, 32, 33, 31, 31, 29, 19, 33), ACTCM75 = c(35, 35, 35, 35, 
36, 35, 36, 35, 31, 35, 35, 35, 35, 34, 34, 33, 24, 35), SAT_AVG = c(1517, 
1503, 1522, 1511, 1547, 1473, 1557, 1526, 1327, 1513, 1517, 1487, 
1511, 1437, 1429, 1380, 1100, 1517), DISTANCEONLY = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), UGDS = c(5308, 
6994, 6546, 10774, 4516, 7141, 938, 893, 4157, 6535, 6089, 14976, 
8221, 9637, 3641, 5164, 1654, 7547), CURROPER = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), COSTT4_A = c(70900, 
71587, 75105, 75303, 70240, 73840, 72084, 76953, 68577, 72265, 
73900, 73879, 76907, 73053, 68734, 68383, 27858, 73485), COSTT4_P = c("NULL", 
"NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
"NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
"NULL"), TUITIONFEE_IN = c(52800, 53529, 58031, 57770, 53790, 
56058, 54600, 58660, 51830, 57119, 55500, 57222, 61788, 57910, 
54014, 55240, 10018, 51925), TUITIONFEE_OUT = c(52800, 53529, 
58031, 57770, 53790, 56058, 54600, 58660, 51830, 57119, 55500, 
57222, 61788, 57910, 54014, 55240, 25752, 51925), AVGFACSAL = c(20724, 
20865, 16863, 18277, 19624, 15798, 20595, 14397, 14592, 12296, 
19830, 15574, 19431, 15599, 15318, 13763, 8928, 20988), PFTFAC = c("0.835", 
"0.9881", "0.9364", "0.7779", "0.9885", "0.4815", "0.9289", "0.8992", 
"0.6696", "0.9161", "0.717", "0.9074", "0.4521", "0.6662", "1", 
"0.8392", "0.5867", "0.862"), C150_4 = c(0.979, 0.9432, 0.9462, 
0.96, 0.954, 0.9491, 0.9357, 0.9167, 0.8952, 0.9049, 0.972, 0.9453, 
0.9549, 0.9404, 0.8473, 0.8981, 0.7629, 0.971), RET_FT4 = c(0.9768, 
0.9876, 0.9827, 0.9808, 0.9946, 0.9679, 0.9826, 0.9744, 0.9201, 
0.9732, 0.9892, 0.9748, 0.9853, 0.9467, 0.9394, 0.9349, 0.8672, 
0.9722), RET_PT4 = c("NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "0.9245", "NULL", 
"0.6667", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "0.95", 
"NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL"), MD_EARN_WNE_P10 = c("95689", 
"97798", "93115", "103246", "111222", "96375", "112166", "108988", 
"107974", "99998", "88655", "91176", "89871", "93021", "98159", 
"95033", "91668", "84918"), PCT25_EARN_WNE_P10 = c("52729", "61965", 
"61558", "65218", "67120", "61372", "67501", "69466", "73117", 
"62003", "60311", "59566", "56005", "62006", "72669", "65644", 
"68187", "56301"), PCT75_EARN_WNE_P10 = c("167686", "172245", 
"151838", "174907", "169465", "147685", "175675", "173725", "146079", 
"159483", "146102", "147189", "141158", "147010", "127298", "134075", 
"129421", "153746"), MD_EARN_WNE_P6 = c("84713", "88873", "77260", 
"80445", "112623", "71107", "129420", "112059", "78514", "87824", 
"72046", "78779", "79434", "70858", "82237", "79832", "79354", 
"77816"), GRAD_DEBT_MDN_SUPP = c("10450", "12000", "13500", "16763", 
"13418", "16500", "PrivacySuppressed", "22089", "25000", "22014", 
"13142", "14500", "21500", "18000", "27000", "23000", "26000", 
"12665"), GRAD_DEBT_MDN10YR_SUPP = c("104.4654099", "119.9602793", 
"134.9553142", "167.5745134", "134.1355856", "164.945384", "PrivacySuppressed", 
"220.8168841", "249.9172485", "220.0671323", "131.3764992", "144.9520041", 
"214.9288337", "179.9404189", "269.9106283", "229.9238686", "259.9139384", 
"126.6080781"), C100_4 = c(0.898, 0.7288, 0.8831, 0.8571, 0.8691, 
0.9076, 0.8434, 0.8565, 0.8479, 0.7599, 0.8777, 0.8694, 0.8635, 
0.9003, 0.4566, 0.8003, 0.6322, 0.8476), ICLEVEL = c(1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), OPENADMP = c(2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), GRADS = c("2997", 
"10253", "10037", "14803", "6990", "12080", "1299", "NULL", "1086", 
"7562", "7517", "8984", "23235", "4846", "3624", "1775", "97", 
"21592"), ACCREDCODE = c("MSACHE", "WASCSR", "SACSCC", "MSACHE", 
"NECHE", "MSACHE", "WASCSR", "WASCSR", "NECHE", "MSACHE", "NECHE", 
"MSACHE", "MSACHE", "NECHE", "MSACHE", "MSACHE", "NECHE", "NECHE"
), RET_FT4_POOLED = c(0.9788, 0.9879, 0.9793, 0.9821, 0.9909, 
0.9651, 0.9806, 0.9716, 0.9262, 0.97, 0.9892, 0.9741, 0.9825, 
0.9479, 0.9423, 0.9378, 0.8633, 0.9817), C100_4_POOLED = c(0.8856, 
0.739, 0.8788, 0.8546, 0.8602, 0.9009, 0.8242, 0.8551, 0.8326, 
0.7546, 0.8772, 0.8766, 0.8677, 0.8918, 0.4515, 0.7621, 0.5955, 
0.8573), BOOKSUPPLY = c("1050", "1245", "1434", "1358", "820", 
"1200", "1428", "800", "1300", "1000", "1050", "970", "1294", 
"1250", "1200", "1000", "1500", "1000"), ADMCON7 = c(1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1), MDCOMP_ALL = c(0.5845, 
0.5845, 0.5845, 0.5845, 0.5845, 0.5845, 0.5845, 0.5845, 0.5845, 
0.5845, 0.5845, 0.5845, 0.5845, 0.5845, 0.5845, 0.5845, 0.5845, 
0.5845), MDCOST_ALL = c(15387.5, 15387.5, 15387.5, 15387.5, 15387.5, 
15387.5, 15387.5, 15387.5, 15387.5, 15387.5, 15387.5, 15387.5, 
15387.5, 15387.5, 15387.5, 15387.5, 15387.5, 15387.5), MDEARN_ALL = c(37078, 
37078, 37078, 37078, 37078, 37078, 37078, 37078, 37078, 37078, 
37078, 37078, 37078, 37078, 37078, 37078, 37078, 37078), PPTUG_EF = c(0, 
0, 0.0031, 0.0537, 0.0064, 0.0214, 0, 0.0011, 0.0118, 0.017, 
2e-04, 3e-04, 0.0633, 0.0127, 0, 0.0128, 0.023, 0.0745), INEXPFTE = c(60048, 
113338, 68756, 56874, 80756, 31693, 105185, 34419, 15842, 28167, 
57231, 29893, 96463, 23266, 12504, 24995, 9687, 46272), C150_4_POOLED = c(0.9712, 
0.9435, 0.9512, 0.9574, 0.9477, 0.9452, 0.9278, 0.9179, 0.8917, 
0.8968, 0.969, 0.9452, 0.9566, 0.9297, 0.8608, 0.886, 0.7484, 
0.974), GRAD_DEBT_MDN = c("10450", "12000", "13500", "16763", 
"13418", "16500", "17747", "22089", "25000", "22014", "13142", 
"14500", "21500", "18000", "27000", "23000", "26000", "12665"
), x = c(2107384.76948701, -1933340.27810509, 1876178.25472949, 
2077243.02501463, 2314261.77712267, 1955381.08673633, -1660141.85673732, 
-1623368.30493136, 2303424.70345276, 1678023.03854027, 2211596.23078863, 
1896995.53745184, 2147624.50302849, 2309370.68277906, 2144734.86774305, 
2041573.64168227, 2373567.48443726, 2311783.20749272), y = c(-188894.792987744, 
-582296.149881856, -762721.806918975, -245389.810253038, 123275.753360416, 
-404107.357328073, -1027748.36033576, -1039201.65863312, 122405.777575308, 
-300870.762534603, -39714.5927185968, -7748.73302456512, -121333.925485063, 
118650.586978148, -129820.607837031, -179439.260821836, 71069.0976923304, 
124173.1993115)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L
))
```

Comment: One option is to make `nudge_x` push labels out to sea by replacing a fixed value of `20` with `ifelse(x > 500, 50, -50)` or something similar. Also increase `force` to push labels away from each other. Finally, you can `expand_limits` to give more space for the labels to move into.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @DanAdams. Regarding the syntax for adding the ifelse clause, what's the syntax for that? I tried `nudge_x = ifelse(x>500)`, but I get `Error in ifelse(x > 500, 50, -50) : object 'x' not found`? Thanks again.

Comment: If you conditionally want to set `nudge_x` based on the data you have to move it inside `aes()`, i.e. `aes(..., nudge_x  = ifelse(x > 500, 50, -50))`

Comment: I think there would be neater ways of representing this data than using ggrepel. Do you have data or a script to generate the data so that we can suggest an alternative?

Comment: What you're looking for are the `xlim` and `ylim` arguments inside `geom_label_repel()`.  You can use these to constrain labels to specific areas.  In this case, I would constrain the labels on the right side to be in an area outside the map area, and do the same with the left side (constraining to be outside on the left side if you wanted to do that).

Comment: Can you give us the result for `dput(top_18_2_transformed)`?  With that, I can probably post a reasonable answer using the constraints features in `ggrepel`.

Comment: Thanks, @chemdork123, for your reply. The `dput()` is quite long but I'll add it to original post.

Comment: @AllanCameron, does my adding `dput(top_18_2_transformed` to the OP provide  the data you mean? Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a little data manipulation, you could move the labels out to either side of the country an draw segments to connect the labels to the universities:

```r
top_18_2_transformed <- top_18_2_transformed[order(-top_18_2_transformed$y),]
colleges_east <- top_18_2_transformed[top_18_2_transformed$x > 0,]
colleges_west <- top_18_2_transformed[top_18_2_transformed$x < 0,]
colleges_west$lab_x <- -2300000
colleges_west$lab_y <- seq(-1000000, -1500000, -250000)
colleges_east$lab_x <- 2800000
colleges_east$lab_y <- seq(1000000, -2500000, -250000)


plot_usmap(fill = "light blue", alpha = 0.5) +
 geom_text(data = colleges_west, 
           aes(x = lab_x, y = lab_y, label =stringr::str_wrap(INSTNM, 25)),
           hjust = 1, size = 3, lineheight = 0.8) +
  geom_text(data = colleges_east, 
            aes(x = lab_x, y = lab_y, label = stringr::str_wrap(INSTNM, 25)),
            hjust = 0, size = 3, lineheight = 0.8) +
  geom_point(data = top_18_2_transformed, aes(x = x, y = y, size = UGDS),
             color = "red",
             alpha = 0.75) +
  geom_segment(data = colleges_east, 
               aes(x, y, xend = lab_x - 100000, yend = lab_y)) +
  geom_segment(data = colleges_west, 
               aes(x, y, xend = lab_x + 100000, yend = lab_y)) +
  labs(title = "Select Colleges",
       size = "Undergrad Enrollment") +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.35, 0),
        legend.direction = 'horizontal') +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c( -3500000,  4000000),
                  ylim = c(-3000000,   1500000))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton, @Allan Cameron--that's extremely helpful!

Comment: Hi @Allan Cameron, please can you look this question that is create a map: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72004345/how-to-generate-a-map-for-property-cluster

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `ggrepel::geom_*_repel()` won't take `xlim` within `aes()` nor can it accept a `list` of `vector`s to split the constraints of west and east coast labels. However, you can just split them into two separate layers and then it's easier to control. Below I made a function to supply that position to avoid duplicating the code for those layers. Then you have to customize the exact values used in `xlim` and `expand_limits()` to get things to look nice depending on your graphics device etc.

Also IMHO this visualization is very hard to easily get much information out of. The points in the northeast are mostly overlapping and there are so many labels that even when spaced very nicely it is a bit tricky to follow them all. Instead it may be better to have a zoomed in plot for that region and avoid showing lots of space with no data in your plot or other ways to increase the legibility of the plot.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)
library(usmap)

# create function to generate labels and constrain outside map away from the center of the map
college_layers <- function(d) {
  xlimz <- if (all(d$x > 0)) {c(2.5e6, NA)} else {c(NA, -2e6)}
  
  geom_text_repel(
    data = d,
    aes(x, y, label = INSTNM),
    xlim = xlimz,
    ylim = c(-Inf, Inf),
    size = 3,
    force = 20,
    box.padding = 0.3,
    max.overlaps = 30,
    point.padding = NA,
    alpha = 1.0,
    min.segment.length = 0.1,
    segment.color = "black",
    segment.size = 1,
    seed = 1000
  )
}

# plot with separate layer for west coast and east coast
plot_usmap(fill = "light blue", alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_point(
    data = d,
    aes(x = x, y = y, size = UGDS),
    color = "red",
    alpha = 0.75
  ) +
  college_layers(d = filter(d, x > 0)) +
  college_layers(d = filter(d, x < 0)) +
  expand_limits(x = c(-3.9e6, 4.6e6),
                y = c(-3e6, 2e6)) +
  labs(title = "Select Colleges",
       size = "Undergrad Enrollment") +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.35, 0),
        legend.direction = 'horizontal',
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

### Data:

```r
d <- structure(list(INSTNM = c("Princeton University", "Stanford University", 
"Duke University", "University of Pennsylvania", "Massachusetts Institute of Technology", 
"Georgetown University", "California Institute of Technology", 
"Harvey Mudd College", "Bentley University", "Carnegie Mellon University", 
"Yale University", "Cornell University", "Columbia University in the City of New York", 
"Boston College", "Stevens Institute of Technology", "Lehigh University", 
"Massachusetts Maritime Academy", "Harvard University"), x = c(2107384.76948701, 
-1933340.27810509, 1876178.25472949, 2077243.02501463, 2314261.77712267, 
1955381.08673633, -1660141.85673732, -1623368.30493136, 2303424.70345276, 
1678023.03854027, 2211596.23078863, 1896995.53745184, 2147624.50302849, 
2309370.68277906, 2144734.86774305, 2041573.64168227, 2373567.48443726, 
2311783.20749272), y = c(-188894.792987744, -582296.149881856, 
-762721.806918975, -245389.810253038, 123275.753360416, -404107.357328073, 
-1027748.36033576, -1039201.65863312, 122405.777575308, -300870.762534603, 
-39714.5927185968, -7748.73302456512, -121333.925485063, 118650.586978148, 
-129820.607837031, -179439.260821836, 71069.0976923304, 124173.1993115
), UGDS = c(5308, 6994, 6546, 10774, 4516, 7141, 938, 893, 4157, 
6535, 6089, 14976, 8221, 9637, 3641, 5164, 1654, 7547)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))
```