# How to generate a map for property cluster

Tags: r, ggplot2, cluster-analysis

Could you help me make a graph in R similar to the one I inserted in the image below, which shows the properties on a map, differentiating by cluster. See in my database that I have 4 properties, properties 1 and 3 are of cluster 1 and properties 2 and 4 are of cluster 2. In addition, the database has the coordinates of the properties, so I believe that with this information I can generate a graph similar to what I inserted. Surely, there must be some package in R that does something similar. Any help is welcome!

This link can help: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/176768_ec7fb4801e3a4772886d61e65885fbdd.html

```
#database

df<-structure(list(Properties = c(1,2,3,4), 
                   Latitude = c(-24.930473, -24.95575,-24.924161,-24.95579), 
                   Longitude = c(-49.994889, -49.990162,-50.004343, -50.007371), 
                   cluster = c(1,2,1,2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

  Properties  Latitude Longitude cluster
1          1 -24.93047 -49.99489       1
2          2 -24.95575 -49.99016       2
3          3 -24.92416 -50.00434       1
4          4 -24.95579 -50.00737       2
```

**Example of figure:**

[image]

**Your code**

```
#database

df<-structure(list(Propertie = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 
30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 38, 39, 40, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 
49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 61, 62, 64, 65, 66, 
67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 
83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 
99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 
112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 
125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 
138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 
151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 
164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 
177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 
190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 
203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 
216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 
229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 
242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 
255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 
268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 
281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 
294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 
307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 
320, 321, 322, 323, 324, 325), Latitude = c(-24.927417, -24.927417, 
-24.927417, -24.927417, -24.930195, -24.930473, -24.946306, -24.949361, 
-24.949361, -24.950195, -24.950195, -24.951584, -24.95575, -24.954084, 
-24.96075, -24.957139, -24.95825, -24.96825, -24.961334, -24.968806, 
-24.976861, -24.982139, -24.986584, -24.985487, -24.994362, -24.994362, 
-24.999084, -24.771583, -24.77186, -24.772138, -24.772138, -24.78686, 
-24.78436, -24.872139, -24.822222, -24.83549, -24.874916, -24.874916, 
-24.874639, -24.865472, -24.873838, -24.87325, -24.858611, -24.874361, 
-24.874361, -24.86, -24.860472, -24.874916, -24.814638, -24.814666, 
-24.818527, -24.818527, -24.822694, -24.822694, -24.845472, -24.844638, 
-24.878528, -24.879639, -24.879639, -24.906028, -24.897972, -24.900278, 
-24.900278, -24.90075, -24.902972, -24.899361, -24.898611, -24.899083, 
-24.913889, -24.908333, -24.914361, -24.914361, -24.924361, -24.915472, 
-24.91075, -24.913805, -24.913528, -24.912139, -24.919917, -24.914083, 
-24.914361, -24.914361, -24.925194, -24.92575, -24.928528, -24.929361, 
-24.934361, -24.935278, -24.922694, -24.927139, -24.927972, -24.931861, 
-24.936861, -24.878537, -24.887972, -24.882972, -24.901583, -24.901667, 
-24.902139, -24.902139, -24.90325, -24.902972, -24.90299, -24.90575, 
-24.905791, -24.899639, -24.899083, -24.875472, -24.878805, -24.883805, 
-24.884916, -24.8905, -24.884083, -24.884087, -24.905194, -24.904125, 
-24.894722, -24.895222, -24.895194, -24.911028, -24.907972, -24.908805, 
-24.919916, -24.919361, -24.919639, -24.919639, -24.920194, -24.920472, 
-24.917972, -24.908805, -24.911305, -24.91325, -24.917416, -24.928528, 
-24.929083, -24.92325, -24.923805, -24.93188, -24.932139, -24.936028, 
-24.935472, -24.937139, -24.923805, -24.922139, -24.922139, -24.926861, 
-24.908805, -24.908333, -24.908805, -24.913805, -24.913805, -24.929638, 
-24.939917, -24.943806, -24.942695, -24.94325, -24.944639, -24.946028, 
-24.94825, -24.954084, -24.956111, -24.958611, -24.958806, -24.959084, 
-24.958528, -24.958528, -24.956584, -24.955833, -24.95825, -24.960833, 
-24.967417, -24.962695, -24.958611, -24.959083, -24.96075, -24.96075, 
-24.964361, -24.961306, -24.961028, -24.962417, -24.965833, -24.964639, 
-24.963806, -24.964917, -24.965472, -24.966861, -24.968528, -24.942972, 
-24.948611, -24.950556, -24.951028, -24.951028, -24.93825, -24.941889, 
-24.943528, -24.944639, -24.945194, -24.945472, -24.949083, -24.946861, 
-24.94825, -24.949361, -24.951306, -24.948805, -24.948, -24.95075, 
-24.952694, -24.959722, -24.961583, -24.96325, -24.96325, -24.96325, 
-24.964639, -24.96575, -24.959361, -24.954639, -24.960472, -24.960472, 
-24.966583, -24.970195, -24.972417, -24.976306, -24.974084, -24.974167, 
-24.974639, -24.979362, -24.979639, -24.980278, -24.982973, -24.982973, 
-24.977417, -24.979639, -24.981028, -24.981028, -24.98325, -24.969361, 
-24.988056, -24.987139, -24.987139, -24.986584, -24.984639, -24.984639, 
-24.984917, -24.984917, -24.994917, -24.987139, -24.989917, -24.992139, 
-24.991861, -24.991861, -24.989639, -24.989917, -24.989917, -24.991861, 
-24.989639, -24.992417, -24.975195, -24.97325, -24.979361, -24.972694, 
-24.972972, -24.942417, -24.941861, -24.93825, -24.938273, -24.949639, 
-24.948333, -24.948805, -24.949639, -24.949639, -24.951615, -24.951583, 
-24.951615, -24.953611, -24.954639, -24.954639, -24.954639, -24.956861, 
-24.956861, -24.966028, -24.956861, -24.955556, -24.957176, -24.96075, 
-24.960194, -24.960231, -24.980194, -24.969106, -24.986306, -24.986306, 
-24.993806, -24.877972, -24.878889, -24.87686, -24.886305, -24.875749, 
-24.876305, -24.876319, -24.878805, -24.891027, -24.898527, -24.898527, 
-24.904083, -24.904083, -24.905, -24.901328, -24.902138, -24.898268, 
-24.900782, -24.901305, -24.88493, -24.887138, -24.929638, -25.001862, 
-25.004084, -25.011028, -25.000194, -25.000472), Longitude = c(-49.98793, 
-49.98793, -49.98793, -49.988778, -49.98962, -49.994889, -49.999912, 
-49.991273, -49.991273, -49.996551, -49.996551, -49.995704, -49.990162, 
-49.992945, -49.990718, -49.999056, -49.998222, -49.981259, -49.997389, 
-49.979357, -49.999908, -49.995713, -49.980449, -49.995736, -49.980444, 
-49.980444, -49.986852, -50.200149, -50.200172, -50.199602, -50.199603, 
-50.199339, -50.209899, -50.038787, -50.243338, -50.235446, -50.139343, 
-50.139348, -50.154871, -50.164607, -50.179621, -50.179895, -50.226412, 
-50.196297, -50.196297, -50.233639, -50.234066, -50.242649, -50.251816, 
-50.252098, -50.258233, -50.258233, -50.288502, -50.288525, -50.251001, 
-50.261575, -50.039037, -50.044333, -50.044333, -50.015148, -50.115163, 
-50.094472, -50.094472, -50.094899, -50.108204, -50.111829, -50.113653, 
-50.114079, -50.010278, -50.017523, -50.010704, -50.010704, -50.004343, 
-50.087667, -50.106547, -50.103487, -50.116283, -50.117968, -50.101301, 
-50.119913, -50.120191, -50.120191, -50.079593, -50.080167, -50.082112, 
-50.093519, -50.070172, -50.074194, -50.095459, -50.117959, -50.121024, 
-50.094079, -50.102677, -50.129635, -50.140468, -50.143492, -50.166288, 
-50.166426, -50.166816, -50.166844, -50.166024, -50.169635, -50.169635, 
-50.165154, -50.165154, -50.175427, -50.182686, -50.188496, -50.203515, 
-50.208765, -50.208487, -50.220728, -50.24933, -50.24933, -50.190159, 
-50.204603, -50.241421, -50.241576, -50.241849, -50.135746, -50.144894, 
-50.142117, -50.14408, -50.146839, -50.148223, -50.148223, -50.143802, 
-50.144066, -50.151269, -50.163802, -50.159357, -50.160168, -50.159066, 
-50.138232, -50.137107, -50.151288, -50.151001, -50.137376, -50.139061, 
-50.132691, -50.132968, -50.152399, -50.170709, -50.176566, -50.176566, 
-50.173237, -50.195182, -50.196949, -50.197376, -50.209608, -50.209608, 
-50.239872, -50.007371, -50.006579, -50.007931, -50.008523, -50.01044, 
-50.013787, -50.014607, -50.014037, -50.013056, -50.004181, -50.006569, 
-50.004607, -50.008482, -50.008482, -50.026278, -50.030861, -50.018523, 
-50.019444, -50.014903, -50.020181, -50.045875, -50.046301, -50.057121, 
-50.057121, -50.036278, -50.040176, -50.043227, -50.044894, -50.036125, 
-50.050158, -50.055186, -50.04876, -50.053213, -50.062385, -50.061561, 
-50.085727, -50.093361, -50.083352, -50.083227, -50.083228, -50.10488, 
-50.10351, -50.108783, -50.121816, -50.121279, -50.098487, -50.093788, 
-50.104315, -50.10238, -50.107121, -50.108482, -50.111024, -50.124043, 
-50.115723, -50.124343, -50.083375, -50.074315, -50.073515, -50.073514, 
-50.073769, -50.070459, -50.072959, -50.106561, -50.116857, -50.113797, 
-50.113797, -50.103802, -50.007107, -50.001815, -50.005185, -50.022371, 
-50.021685, -50.022111, -50.004597, -50.006269, -50.007778, -50.001843, 
-50.001843, -50.01906, -50.020185, -50.020185, -50.020426, -50.021843, 
-50.06044, -50.00362, -50.00519, -50.00519, -50.007102, -50.024079, 
-50.024079, -50.023778, -50.023778, -50.010732, -50.037686, -50.032936, 
-50.03657, -50.038204, -50.038223, -50.041283, -50.042375, -50.044885, 
-50.043227, -50.05851, -50.03988, -50.062653, -50.087385, -50.077112, 
-50.110996, -50.119061, -50.126279, -50.132691, -50.149052, -50.149052, 
-50.137371, -50.141431, -50.141858, -50.170992, -50.170992, -50.176288, 
-50.176844, -50.176844, -50.14225, -50.142404, -50.142404, -50.142408, 
-50.155432, -50.155432, -50.14852, -50.159344, -50.160579, -50.157409, 
-50.158209, -50.170436, -50.170436, -50.132121, -50.165154, -50.144052, 
-50.144052, -50.13408, -50.263247, -50.264755, -50.26821, -50.257386, 
-50.28265, -50.2924, -50.2924, -50.303516, -50.264891, -50.251543, 
-50.251543, -50.261302, -50.261539, -50.264755, -50.270455, -50.270747, 
-50.294067, -50.290159, -50.290432, -50.315715, -50.320456, -50.251849, 
-49.989338, -49.986551, -49.976296, -50.127404, -50.127654), 
    cluster = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 
    4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
    5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
    5, 5, 5, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
    5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5)), row.names = c(NA, 
-318L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


w1<-convexhull.xy(df$Longitude[df$cluster==1], df$Latitude[df$cluster==1])
w2<-convexhull.xy(df$Longitude[df$cluster==2], df$Latitude[df$cluster==2])
w3<-convexhull.xy(df$Longitude[df$cluster==3], df$Latitude[df$cluster==3])
w4<-convexhull.xy(df$Longitude[df$cluster==4], df$Latitude[df$cluster==4])
w5<-convexhull.xy(df$Longitude[df$cluster==5], df$Latitude[df$cluster==5])

p1<-st_as_sf(w1, crs=4269)
p2<-st_as_sf(w2, crs=4269)
p3<-st_as_sf(w3, crs=4269)
p4<-st_as_sf(w4, crs=4269)
p5<-st_as_sf(w5, crs=4269)

poly<-rbind(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5)
poly[,"cluster"]<-c(1,2,3,4,5)

pts<-st_as_sf(df, coords=c("Longitude", "Latitude"), crs=4269)

tmap_mode("plot")
tm_shape(poly)+
  tm_polygons(col="cluster", palette=c("darkolivegreen","skyblue","skyblue","yellow","pink"), style="cat", title="cluster")+
  tm_shape(pts)+
  tm_dots(size=2)+
  tm_layout(legend.outside = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you want something like this: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ClustGeo/vignettes/intro_ClustGeo.html

Comment: Hi @Quinten, thanks for the suggestion. I took a look and it seems to me that it can be used for this question. But I couldn't get it to work. If you can try, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: Quick point of clarification...Are you wanting the polygons to be drawn based on some sort of hull around the point data, or are you wanting to overlay the points on two polygons and then color the polygons according to the cluster?

Comment: Thanks for replying @Sean McKenzie. I think your second suggestion. The idea is to take the points and to overly in one/two polygons, I don't know, I believe it's one, because they're in the same region. See this link: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/176768_ec7fb4801e3a4772886d61e65885fbdd.html that it does something similar in the same polygon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be use a voronoi partition.  `ggvoronoi` will do this for you with `ggplot2`, and you could easily overlay it on a `ggmap` map.

There is also a `st_voronoi` function in the `sf` package which will create a voronoi partition shapefile from a MULTIPOINT shape (see update below).

Here is a simple example using your data. I have removed duplicated points (i.e. the same point in different clusters) which break the voronoi algorithm!

```
library(tidyverse) #specifically ggplot2 and dplyr for the pipe
library(ggvoronoi)

df %>% distinct(Longitude, Latitude, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, fill = factor(cluster), label = cluster)) +
  geom_voronoi() +
  geom_text()
```

[image]

**Update:**

To do this with `sf_voronoi` you can do the following (unlike `ggvoronoi`, `sf_voronoi` works without having to weed out the duplicates)...

```
pts_vor <- pts %>% st_union() %>%    #merge points into a MULTIPOINT
       st_voronoi() %>%              #calculate voronoi polygons
       st_cast() %>%                 #next three lines return it to a useable list of polygons
       data.frame(geometry = .) %>%  
       st_sf(.) %>%
       st_join(., pts)               #merge with clusters and other variables
  
pts_vor %>% ggplot(aes(fill = factor(cluster))) + 
       geom_sf(colour = NA) +        #draw voronoi tiles (no borders)
       geom_sf_text(data = pts, aes(label = cluster)) + #plot points
       coord_sf(xlim = c(-50.35, -49.95), ylim = c(-25.05, -24.75))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

@Antonio, I think this might be the solution you are after, but it requires at least three points per cluster to work, which from your figure I am assuming you have in your full dataset.  The trick is to create convex hulls and convert them into polygons.  This can be accomplished using the `convexhull.xy()` function in the `spatstat::` package.  Then these can be converted into simple features in the `sf::` package, and then drawn with your mapping package of choice.  I personally am a fan of the `tmap::` package.  Here is a reproducible example.  Note, I had to add two more points to your example data to make this work (you cannot compute a polygon from only two points).

```
##Loading Necessary Packages##
library(spatstat)#For convexhull.xy() function
library(tmap)# For drawing the map
library(sf) #To create simple features for mapping

##Loading Example Data##
df<-structure(list(Properties = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), 
                   Latitude = c(-24.930473, -24.95575,-24.924161,-24.95579, -24.94557, -24.93267), 
                   Longitude = c(-49.994889, -49.990162,-50.004343, -50.007371, -50.01542, -50.00702), 
                   cluster = c(1,2,1,2,1,2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

##Calculating convexhulls for each cluster##
w1<-convexhull.xy(df$Longitude[df$cluster==1], df$Latitude[df$cluster==1])
w2<-convexhull.xy(df$Longitude[df$cluster==2], df$Latitude[df$cluster==2])

##Converting hulls to simple features.  Note, I assumed that you are using the EPSG 4269 projection (WGS84)
p1<-st_as_sf(w1, crs=4269)
p2<-st_as_sf(w2, crs=4269)

#Combining the two simple features together
poly<-rbind(p1,p2)

#Labelling the clusters
poly[,"cluster"]<-c(1,2)

#Creating a point simple feature from your property data in the dataframe
pts<-st_as_sf(df, coords=c("Longitude", "Latitude"), crs=4269)

#Setting the mapping mode to plot.  Change this to "view" if you want an interactive map
tmap_mode("plot")

#Drawing the map
tm_shape(poly)+
  tm_polygons(col="cluster", palette=c("darkolivegreen", "skyblue"), style="cat", title="cluster")+
tm_shape(pts)+
  tm_dots(size=2)+
tm_layout(legend.outside = TRUE)
```

[image: Map Output]

Comment: Hi @Sean! Thank you very much for your reply. I used your code for a real database and inserted it into the question as you can see. However, I have two doubts: See that the black dots became large, how to decrease the size? And the other issue is that the polygons are made separately and then the cluster is made. But wouldn't it be possible to do something similar to the image, that is, have the map of the region, then join the clusters?

Comment: Hi @Antonio.  For your first concern (the size of the dots), that is easily fixed.  In the call to `tm_dots()` simply reduce the value in the argument `size=`.  In my original post I have `tm_dots(size=2)` try `tm_dots(size=0.5)` and see if that is a more appropriate size.  For your second concern, I think that perhaps the solution would to be to create a hull for all points, and then use geoprocessing functions to create topologically correct clusters.   I will see if I can work up a solution using that approach.

Comment: Thank you so much for this @Sean McKenzie! I will wait!